# Magento 2 - Update qty & Addresses Button Not updating first item on Ship to Multiple Addresses page in Multishipping

Tags: magento2

I am using magento version 2.1.8 and facing issue while multishipping address save.

if you have more item in cart and your in Ship to Multiple Addresses of multishipping page

and then change the address from drop and click update qty & addresses Button

it will update other item address but first item address will be set to first address not which one we selected from address drop-down